# Overloading operator% for floating types

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I'm trying to overload the operator % because you can't use modulus on double types,

```
float a = 5.0; 
float b = 5.0;
a  = a % b;
// not allowed
```

I Was trying to overload the operator % with this kind of function :

```
template <>
MyClass*                MyClass<float>::operator%(Myclass &other)
```

For other operation non involving float I use :

```
template <class T>
MyClass*                MyClass<T>::operator%(MyClass &other)
```

It never compiled actually I'm stuck and can't find a way to bypass this problem,
g++ is still warning me that you can't perform modulo on floats, is something wrong 
with my template syntax or is it really impossible.

Comment: There's a function `fmod()` in `<cmath>` you can use.

Comment: It compiled without the operator% overload divide etc works just fine but g++ warns me whenever I tried to overload % in my templetated class. Thanks you for fmod()!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't overload operators for primitive types the way you'd want it to work.

For C++11 draft n3290, §13.5 *Operator Overloads*, point 6:

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration. [...]

Primitive types aren't classes (or enums), so they can't have member functions. And you can't create a global `float operator%(float&,float&)` since that doesn't involve a class or enum in the parameter list. (See also [C++FAQ 26.10 "Can I define an operator overload that works with built-in / intrinsic / primitive types?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/intrinsic-types.html#faq-26.10).)
You need at least one of the terms in the `%` expression to be a user-defined type.

You could create a class `Float` and define whatever operations you want on it, but you cannot get `a = a % b;` to use your function if both `a` and `b` are `float`s.

Or you could `#include <cmath>` and use `std::fmod`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float a = 13.0f;
    float b = 5.0f;
    a  = std::fmod(a, b);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Simple example with a custom "float wrapper" (incomplete, probably not quite safe as-is, but can get you started):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Float {
    private:
        float val;
    public:
        Float(float f): val(f) {};

        Float operator%(Float const& other) const {
            return std::fmod(val, other.val);
        }
        Float operator%(float const& other) const {
            return std::fmod(val, other);
        }
        // conversion operator could be handy
        operator float() { return val; }
};

int main()
{
    Float a = 13.0f;
    Float b = 5.0f;
    Float c  = a % b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    // this also works
    Float d = 13.0f;
    float e = 5.0f;
    float f  = d % e;
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A +1 answer should also mention `fmod`, and explain _why_ default C++ doesn't do floating point modulo.

Comment: My example was to show what's impossible, I'm using the overload on the MyClass class, which is templated to inside it I've a T _value variables. I'm sorry if you got it just clarifying stuff it wasn't clear I guess sorry thanks you for the help I guess I'm going to use fmod().

Comment: You can also use a different syntax that may look more natural: `float f = (Float)13 % 5;`

Comment: Well, that works with GCC, but clang++ doesn't like it (ambiguous with all the int `%` operators unless you cast both sides). Not sure which one is 'right', don't know the rules well enough for this. (That's why I put the disclaimer "probably not quite safe" in there :-) )