# Translating GLSL to C++ float / vec3?

Tags: c++, glsl

What does this line exactly do

```
ra.rgb * ra.w / max(ra.r, 1e-4) * (bR.r / bR);
```

The part I am confused about is how to translate

```
(bR.r / bR);
```

A float divided by a vec3?
I want to translate this to C++ but what is that returning a float divided by all the elements of the vector? etc

(no access to graphics card to check?)

Comment: According to the spec, it is a componentwise divide.

Comment: I would say that this is the answer to your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753158/glsl-vector-plus-scalar

Comment: Unless you make a wrapper class to encapsulate `float` I don't think you'll be able to translate this to C++ since you can't overload operators of primitive types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201497/overloading-operator-for-floating-types

Comment: (Access to NV and AMD hardware to check) ==> `(bR.r/bR) == vec3 (1.0, bR.r/bR.g, bR.r/bR.b)`, see answer for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of component-wise division, and it works as follows:

#### [GLSL 4.40 Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) - 5.9 Expressions - pp. 101-102

> If the fundamental types in the operands do not match, then the conversions from section **4.1.10** *“Implicit Conversions”* are applied to create matching types. [...] After conversion, the following cases are valid:
>
> > [...]
> >
> > - One operand is a scalar, and the other is a vector or matrix. In this case, the scalar operation is applied independently to each component of the vector or matrix, resulting in the same size vector or matrix.

#### Given the expression:

```
        vv vec3
(bR.r / bR);
    ^ float
```

The scalar `bR.r` is essentially promoted to `vec3 (bR.r, bR.r, bR.r)` and then component-wise division is performed, resulting in `vec3 (bR.r/bR.r, bR.r/bR.g, bR.r/bR.b)`.

#### Thus, this expression is equivalent to:

```
vec3 (1.0, bR.r/bR.g, bR.r/bR.b)
```